# Cinnamon running in software rendering mode while Unity and Gnome work fine

Tags: cinnamon

I'm running Ubuntu 12.04 32bit with Intel Atom CPU N2800 and GMA3600 graphics chipset (Lenovo S110). I have the drivers "Intel Cedarview graphics driver" and "drm driver for the Intel GMA500" both "activated and currently in use" in the Additional Drivers window. Unity and Gnome work perfect, but when logging in with Cinnamon it runs in software rendering mode, not recognizing the graphics driver.

This Intel graphics chipset have a really bad support for linux and the proprietary and outdated driver will only work with this kernel version (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Intel_GMA3600).

Thanks in advance, any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cinnamon won't work with this gpu. I solved the problem installing Linux Mint 13 Maya MATE edition 32bit, which is based on Ubuntu 12.04 and is also LTS with support till 2017. Or maybe you can try MATE under Ubuntu 12.04?

I, then, updated the system and installed `cedarview-graphics-driver` and `cedarview-drm` and the system runs just great.

MATE is very similar to Cinnamon and is really customizable. Give it a try, or stay with Gnome or another DE if you don't like it. You can also backport MATE 1.6 to Linux Mint 13 as described here: http://blog.linuxmint.com/?p=2524

Comment: Gnome? Do you mean Gnome3? How you get it to work?

Comment: @GunJack Unity and Gnome worked out of the box after installing the drivers. I didn't check the Gnome version, but i believe it was Gnome3 fallback mode. I didn't install Gnome, I just was able to select it at the login screen alongside Unity.

Comment: I believe that gnone was installed along with Cinnamon. How is Mint 13 Cinnamon performing compared to Ubuntu 12.04.1's Unity? Is the kernel version > 3.2

Comment: @GunJack The kernel version is 3.2 indeed. Yes, I also think Gnome came with Cinnamon. As i said, I wasn't able to run Cinnamon properly in this laptop, but i have it in my desktop PC, and both Unity and Cinnamon perform great, fast and smooth. It's just I prefer Cinnamon rather than Unity. This is why I love Linux, you can have the desktop environment you want in the distro you want.

Comment: Well you are not left with much of a choice if you own a device with a brick in place of graphics card. You know what I am pointing at

Comment: Jajaja that's true. But Linux is so flexible that, even without official support, you can run it even in a device with a brick inside of it :D

Comment: Thats the beauty of it. But still its a felony on the part of Intel. What hurts the most that we at user level feels powerless and ignored.

Comment: I recommend you this post: http://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=59&t=117150&p=763882&hilit=gma3600
It's really useful